# VB.Net - Passing function with return value through constructor

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I have an app which uses about 89 different UserControls with very similar methods. I have made a base class for these UserControls with the similar methods within. Four of these methods call a function for selecting, inserting, deleting, and updating database records. My idea to handle this was to pass in these four database functions as parameters to the base class, and reference them in these base methods when I need them. Pseudo Code:

```
Public MustInherit Class MyAbstractBaseClass
    Inherits UserControl

    // Protected DatabaseInsertFunction(Of IDBRecord) As Boolean
    // Protected DatabaseDeleteFunction(Of IDBRecord) As Boolean
    // Protected DatabaseSelectFunction(Of IDBRecord) As Boolean
    // Protected DatabaseUpdateFunction(Of IDBRecord) As Boolean

    Public Sub New( InsertFunc, ...)
        // Me.DatabaseInsertFun = InsertFun
        ...
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DoWork(someObject As IDBRecord)
        // Do some work here
        Dim result As Boolean = DatabaseInsertFunction(someObject)
        ...
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyDerivedClass
    Inherits MyAbstractBaseClass

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(AddressOf InsertRecord)
    End Sub

    Private Sub InsertRecord(someObj as IDBRecord) As Boolean
        // some work here
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have tried every variation of syntax I can find on Google and it continues to elude me. Looking at the above code snippet, I would like to pass in the function from the derived class to the base class upon construction and store it in the base' class fields so that they can be called upon by different methods within the base class later. Using  Func(Of T) is great except when there are return values I can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Looks like they would be `Func(Of IDBRecord, Boolean)`, but wouldn't it be cleaner to define abstract functions (`MustOverride`) in `MyAbstractBaseClass` and implement in the derived classes?

Comment: @Mark yes it would be cleaner thanks for that I will do so. As for the Func(Of IDBRecord, Boolean) signature, is it just understood that the last parameter is the return value? I recall seeing something like Func(Of T, TResult) but didn't understand how to differentiate between a Func with two parameters and one that was intended to be one parameter paired with a return value. Thanks for the quick response man

Comment: Yes, with the `Func` delegates, the last generic parameter is the return type, and any others are the argument types.  For Subs (void methods), you would use one of the `Action` delegate types. e.g. `Func(Of T, TResult)` is `Function X(param As T) As TResult` and `Action(Of T)` is `Sub X(param As T)`.

Comment: @Mark Awesome thanks for taking the time to respond